# fluent-nhibernate HasOne relationship returning NULL

Tags: asp.net-mvc, fluent-nhibernate, domain-driven-design

I'm having some difficulties representing my desired outcome within fluent-nhibernate. Perhaps I'm simply taking the wrong approach on such a simple concept.

The People entity is populated from a 3rd party service. At a later date an account ( credentials along with a guid that will be used as an api key) can be generated. A user will only have one set of credentials and credentials are unique per user.

Within the web application admin area it is desired to list some properties of the People entity along with their UserName.

*Ultimately when querying for all people entities, the `Account` is always NULL.*

- Is this the the incorrect usage of HasOne?

Essentially what I want is to basically perform a left outer join on Account.

```
public class Account
{
    public virtual Guid Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string UserName { get; set; }
    public virtual string Password { get; set; }

    public virtual People People { get; set; }
}

public class People
{
    public virtual int UserID { get; set; }
    public virtual string FirstName { get; set; }
    public virtual string LastName { get; set; }

    public virtual Account Account { get; set; }
    ...
    ...
    ...
}

 public class AccountMap: ClassMap<Account>
    {
        public AccountMap()
        {
            Table("Account");
            LazyLoad();
            Id(x => x.Id).GeneratedBy.Assigned().Column("ID");
            Map(x => x.UserName).Column("UserName").Not.Nullable().Length(100);
            Map(x => x.Password).Column("Password").Not.Nullable().Length(100);
            References(x => x.People).Column("People_id");
        }
    }

public class PeopleMap : ClassMap<People>
{
    public PeopleMap()
    {
        Table("People");
        LazyLoad();
        Id(x => x.UserID).GeneratedBy.Identity().Column("People_id");
        Map(x => x.FirstName).Column("First_Name").Length(50);
        Map(x => x.LastName).Column("Last_Name").Length(50);
        HasOne(x => x.Account).PropertyRef(r => r.People).Cascade.All();
    }
}
```

When running my PersistenceSpecification tests the tables are generating as I would expect:

```
create table Account (
        ID UNIQUEIDENTIFIER not null,
       UserName TEXT not null,
       Password TEXT not null,
       People_id INT,
       primary key (ID),
       constraint FKBE1051AFE1BC1FAE foreign key (People_id) references People
    )
```

Am I doing something totally wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well it turns out that my mappings were correct for what I had wanted to accomplish, however a stateless session had been opened which was ultimately the source of my issues.

Comment: I'm having this exact same issue - my test with the HasOne fails, but only after running my StatelessSession test.  Can you explain what you did to correct this issue?

Comment: @JohnS, when I was opening the session I changed my factory method from SessionFactory.OpenStatelessSession() to SessionFactory.OpenSession();

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you need to use `HasOne` in both the People and Account ClassMap implementations. You currently show Account as `References` People but not the other way around.